# How to Instantiate new structure object?

Tags: c#

Is this correct?

```
//Structure
public struct Shape
{
    public string mShape;
    public int mSide;

    public Shape(/*initial sides parameter*/ int sSide, string sShape)
    {
        mShape = sShape;
        mSide = sSide;
    }

}

//more code here.... but no need to post.
//Instantiate new Shape structure object
myShape = new Shape(/*Sides integer value*/ ,sShape);

//How to Add the additional parameter to construct the object?
```

Comment: Appart from ugly coding conventions and public fields this looks OK to me. And what do you mean by additional parameter?

Comment: Your structure should be immutable (mark all fields as readonly and/or encapsulate fields in properties without setter).

Comment: "structure object" is an oxymoron in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I follow. If your question is, how do you send an integer in the constructor?

Here you go:

```
myShape = new Shape(4, sShape);
```

or:

```
int sides = 4;
myShape = new Shape(sides, sShape);
```

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with CiC why are the fields public? Very dangerous violation of encapsulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29 -- also see references on information hiding...
Also, Shape is pretty vague, right? A square has one value, a rectangle 2 and a circle a circumference..and a polygon could have many.  I thin the subclasses need to implement the sides by extending the superclass. And, in that case, why pass the name of the shape? What is the point of this?

Comment: I understand what you mean but I didn't post all my code and thanks for the link, I can definitely use that.